# Howto migrate hyper-v based virtual machines to to google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, hyper-v

I have used google cloud migrate for migrating VM from AWS to GCP, Azure to GCP, and On-Prem Datacenter (VMware) to GCP. Please share views on **migrating Hyperv -V based VM's to be migrated to Google cloud**

Comment: Your question is too broad to give any meaningful answer. Maybe you could specify more what part of migration from Hyper-V solution interests you ?

Comment: Are there any available tool that helps migrate on-premise  Virtual Machines running on Hyper V to GCP cloud.

Answer (score 2):

As near as I can tell there is no tool for on premises Hyper-V to GCP migration. The only documentation I can find that is helpful talks about uploading the VHD to cloud storage and building an Image from that.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks

I am currently uploading a VHD now and will edit my answer with the result.

Comment: what was your result? :)